# <built-in>:1:2: warning: use of C++0x long long integer constant [-Wlong-long]

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

What is this warning about? It seems to be warning about long long constants in built ins. This is from GCC version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1).

```
In file included from ../include/log4cplus/helpers/stringhelper.h:36:0,
                 from ../tests/performance_test/main.cxx:6:
<built-in>:1:2: warning: use of C++0x long long integer constant [-Wlong-long]
```

Comment: C++03 didn't have `long long`, so the compiler warns. Use `-std=c++11`, in the current standard, `long long` is included.

Comment: @DanielFischer: The problem is that it is not my code that triggers the warning.

Comment: Still, if you tell the compiler to use a standard that includes `long long`, I'd expect it to no longer warn about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the new C++11 standard as Daniel Fischer suggests. However, if you are cross-compiling or just have an older compiler:

```
-Wno-long-long
```

Is a valid compiler flag which will inhibit the warning (of course just from `man gcc`).